# Counting conditional and comma operators

Tags: python, regex, operators

I need to count number of occurrences of conditional (ternary) and comma operators in .c file. Problem is the conditional operator can be of any kind (it can be the easiest one and it can be really long compound one). The same applies to comma operator.

I don't absolutely know how to do that. I thought using regex match to find it, but it's probably not the best option. Have you better idea?

EDIT here is some input file for analysis:

```
int a=x?1:0;                                                     // O_2__TER_1
a = x ? 1 : 0 ;                                                  // O_4__TER_2
a = x   ?   1   :   0   ;                                        // O_6__TER_3
a=((((*(*(*x))))?((1)):((0))));                                  // O_11__TER_4

if(x?1:0){;};                                                    // O_12__TER_5

a = (x)? (y? (z?1:4) : (z?2:3) ) : 1;                            // O_17__TER_9
b = x?y:x?1:0;                                                   // O_20__TER_11

a?
  b?
    c?
      d?
        d
      :
        e?
          e
        :
          f?
            f
          :
            g?
              g
            :
              -g
    :
      -c
  :
    -b
:
  -a;                                                            // O_31__TER_18
```

Output is: 18 ternary operators

Comment: Please show us examples of the code patterns you want to match.  It doesn't matter per se that they be in a `.C` file.

Comment: Matching the ternary operator is going to be a lot easier than the comma operator; the `?` isn't valid (as far as I know) in C except as the ternary operator and in strings, so depending on what your use-case is, a simple `grep '?' file` might be sufficient. For the comma, you'll probably actually need to do some parsing, since the comma can show up in function definitions, function calls, etc...

Comment: In your example input, can't you just count the number of question marks and commas?

Comment: What Stephan said. That test input is too easy. Proper test input needs data that will give false positives with simple character counting algorithms. So the test input needs to have things like string literals containing question marks, commas and parentheses, as well as various function definitions and calls. It should also contain more tricky true positives, like parenthesized expressions containing the comma operator. And to handle all that stuff probably needs a proper parser, as beerbajay suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Following your current description I'd code something like this:

```
def match(operator, filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        data = f.read()
        n = 0
        op_len = len(operator)
        match = data.find(operator)
        while match != -1:
            n += 1
            data = data[match + op_len:] # cut checked part
            match = data.find(operator)

        if n > 0:
            print """Found {0} "{1}" in {2}""".format(n, operator, filename)
        else:
            print """No "{0}" in {1}""".format(operator, filename) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    operators = ["==", ">", "<", ","]  # + any other you want 
    for op in operator:
        match(op, "main.c")
```